# Inequality from Riasat Inequalitus

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

Let a,b,c,d>0 and $a+b+c+d=4$, prove $$\frac{4}{abcd}⩾\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}$$
I found posts about this inequality, but I can't figure out where I'm wrong in my proof because I haven't read mine anywhere yet:
$\frac{4}{abcd}⩾\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}$

$4⩾(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a})(abcd)$

For AM-GM: $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}⩾4$

So $4⩾(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a})(abcd)⩾4(abcd)$.

This implies 1⩾abcd.

Claim: If $a+b+c+d=4$, then $1⩾abcd$

Proof: It's true by AM-GM

Comment: For positive $a,b,c,d?$

Comment: When you write “So $4\geqslant\left(\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac cd+\frac da\right)(abcd)$”, aren't you using what you wish to prove?

Comment: (A) Are you asking for a Proof ? I think not , because you seem to state that you have come across lots of Proofs (B) Are you asking for feedback about your Proof ? Either It is wrong [ because you are assuming that Conclusion to Prove that Conclusion ] or It should be written in a better Sequence [ because it is Currently very Confusing ] (C) Either way , you should try to clarify your Post !

Comment: Sorry for the post, i'm new here. Do you recommend deleting the post or leaving it?

Comment: @afraidguy Don't delete my solution! It's not fair.

Comment: Certainly. I was scared by the many negative comments. it's a nice solution. Thank you.
Do you know of any place where I can find a pen pal to share my solutions?

Answer (score 1):

For positive variables we need to prove that:
$$a^2cd+b^2ad+c^2ab+d^2bc\leq4.$$
Now, let $\{a,b,c,d\}=\{x,y,z,t\},$ where $x\geq y\geq z\geq t$.

Thus, by Rearrangement and AM-GM twice we obtain:
$$a^2cd+b^2ad+c^2ab+d^2bc=a\cdot acd+b\cdot bad+c\cdot cab+d\cdot dbc\leq$$
$$\leq x\cdot xyz+y\cdot xyt+z\cdot xzt+t\cdot yzt=xy(xz+yt)+zt(xz+yt)=$$
$$=(xz+yt)(xy+zt)\leq\left(\frac{xz+yt+xy+zt}{2}\right)^2=$$
$$=\left(\frac{(x+t)(y+z)}{2}\right)^2\leq\left(\frac{\left(\frac{x+t+y+z}{2}\right)^2}{2}\right)^2=4.$$

Comment: The proof requires that only the inequality Am-Gm be used. In any case, thank you very much

Comment: @afraidguy  Maybe you'll fix your open post? Write please that variables are positives. Otherwise, your inequality is wrong.